# Is it bad practice to reuse the same class multiple times, but holding different styles?

Tags: css, class, code-reuse

For example, I want to do something on the first `<li class="first">` of a `<ul>` list.

and I write the CSS:

```
ul .first{
    /*awesome code here*/
}
```

But then, I also want to give a particular CSS to the first `<p class="first">` of my `<div id="content">`.

and I do it like this:

```
#content .first{
    /*awesome code here*/
}
```

In case you didn't noticed, I reused the class `first` to give totally different styles to two totally different cases.

- Is it bad to reuse classes in this way?
- Is there any possibility that this lead to glitches/bugs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine by me because when you are intentionally defining what the first item and paragraph of your structure will look like. Although, it'd be better if you used :first-child pseudo selector but then again both will have different styles because that's what you want.

I hope I'm not missing the big picture here but I'm also wondering what you meant with code reusability in this case?

If you are going to use ul.first then you have to change your

`<li id="first"` to `<li class="first"`

Comment: Thanks for noticing the error, I have updated the question. And about the `:first-child`, I will use it in a couple of years. For now, I am a bit worried about its compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:first-child#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Worried about browser support of `:first-child`? Do you have that many IE6 users to consider? And even if you do, I'd still use it as long as it does not break things in browsers that do not support it.

Comment: @Arjan : I absolutely agree with you on this. I wouldn't worry about non standard browsers unless my client requires it because of their business.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your CSS.

If you want to apply a rule to the first `li` in `ul`, assuming you have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">Something</li>
```

Your css should look like this

```
ul .first {
/* Some code here, notice the space above */
}
```

The same goes with your second statement. By writing `#content.first` you are saying "I mean an object that has an id like `content` **and** has the `first` class". If you add a space, `#content .first`, you then mean "I want to select an object that has the `first` class and sits within an object that has the id `content` assigned to it".

But to answer your question, this is not bad practice, on the contrary - it is recommended for semantic reasons.

Comment: I forgot the space :( again... (I always do), well thanks for the answer. By the way, I think it is not possible to comment like that on CSS... I think you must use `/* */`

Comment: Yeah sorry just quickly wanted indicate what to do there, wasn't thinking about valid comments :)

Answer (score -1):

You should only use this approach when you're sharing styles across elements. That's actually one of the reasons for having classes in CSS. It's so you don't have to repeat the same style for different elements. If you try to apply two different values for the same property then the initial value will be overwritten.

For example:

```
.first
{
color: blue;
color: red; 
}
```

The second style will overwrite the first. Also, even if you don't overwrite the original property, you can still run into issues debugging style bugs. For example, you have inline elements and block level elements so in those cases you may run into issues using this approach.

Updated:
Made blanket statement about CSS classes more general. ;)

Comment: But read my example again, I am giving two different paths, so they should not collide. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/6HaCK/1/

Comment: That's not entirely true my friend, classes are used mainly for semantic reasons so it is even recommended to use the ajax333221's approach.

Comment: Yeah namespacing will definitely avoid the collision. This is definitely a different way of looking at this. I think you do lose one of the benefits of classes going this route. The browser doesn't have to traverse the entire DOM when you use classes the way I mentioned. Your approach does add some overhead (however small). Also, I still think it makes it that much trickier to track down bugs in your styles. In the end though it's really a matter of opinion. :p

Comment: MMM, can you show me where it's recommended? I've never seen this before myself.